# Firebase is not sending data to my Realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to figure this out all day, based on everything I have seen my code is correct, I have not set a .env because I do not think I need one. I am unsure what I could be doing wrong, if anyone has any answers that would be awesome, thank you!

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
const mySecret = "DISCORD_TOKEN";
const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const randomstring = require("randomstring");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

//My details in config are correct I just removed them for security

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = firebase.database();
console.log(database);

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author === client.user) {
    return;
  }
  try {
    let ticket = randomstring.generate(7);
    firebase.database().goOnline();
    await database.ref("/" + ticket).set({
      Message: message.content,
      User: message.author.username,
      User_ID: message.author.id,
      Ticket_Number: ticket,
    });
    console.log("a");
    firebase.database().goOffline();
    client.channels.cache
      .get(`CHANNEL ID`)
      .send(`The code worked? ${ticket} is the reference `);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

client.login(mySecret);
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so you'll need to do some debugging in order to figure out what's going on. For example, if you do a simpler set (`await database.ref("test").set(true);`) does that make it to the database?

Comment: Got nothing sadly

Comment: This `message.author === client.user` could silently fail and you'll never know why. You should output the error message.